# Adding extra fields to UserAdmin

Tags: python, django, admin

i have this custom class

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'location')}
        ),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
    #UserAdmin.list_display += ('location',)
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    form = MyUserChangeForm
```

It works fine, untill i uncomment this line

UserAdmin.list_display += ('location',)

then it gives me this error:
CustomUserAdmin.list_display[5], 'location' is not a callable or an attribute of 'CustomUserAdmin' or found in the model 'User'.

any help?

[Edit]

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to modify UserAdmin right?

Supposing that `location` is an actual field of `CustomUser`, try to use

```
list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ('location',)
```

**EDIT: simpler answer**

Use the standard django way to show custom things in the `list_display`:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # other things

    def user_location(self, u):
        try:
            return u.get_profile().location
        except:
            return ''
    user_location.short_description = 'Location'

    list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ('user_location',)
```

**EDIT: more info**

Anyway, if you are extending the UserForm just for the sake of adding the profile fields, you should look into this link: http://www.thenestedfloat.com/articles/displaying-custom-user-profile-fields-in-djangos-admin/index.html to take advantages of inlines and avoid recreating the whole Form from scratch.

Comment: that didnt seem to help Im still getting the same error. the location field worked for add_fieldsets and fieldsets, so assume it should work for list_display. i also tried doing this:     `list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'location')'` it gave me the same error

Comment: Could you post the `CustomUser` model?

Comment: This question was very helpful (I was using inlines but it still applied) but it wasn't working for me because I forgot to add the following to settings: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'

Comment: The link is broken, here it is from archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170424191936/http://www.thenestedfloat.com/articles/displaying-custom-user-profile-fields-in-djangos-admin/index.html